# How to read tabular format data image and store into csv file using custom vision api?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I have written python code to read text from image and store it into text files. 
I'm able to capture the normal data from image but finding difficult to capture tabular format data from image and store into csv file. I'm able to read one column from image but other columns are missing in output. Is it possible to achieve the solution through custom vision api?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sam, that's not the purpose of Custom Vision, which has 2 capabilities: classification or object detection.

Here you want to parse a form in an image, there a product for that called Form Recognizer API, described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#features)

Have look to the preview samples in the page:
[image: Form recognizer sample]

I made a quick test using your image with the `Analyse Layout` operation  from Form Recognizer (see doc [here](https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-preview/operations/AnalyzeLayoutAsync)), here is the output:

```
{
  "status": "succeeded",
  "createdDateTime": "2020-04-16T17:31:52Z",
  "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2020-04-16T17:31:58Z",
  "analyzeResult": {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "readResults": [{
      "page": 1,
      "language": "en",
      "angle": 0,
      "width": 467,
      "height": 113,
      "unit": "pixel",
      "lines": [{
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [4, 6, 17, 5, 17, 15, 4, 16],
        "text": "#",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [6, 6, 13, 5, 14, 15, 7, 16],
          "text": "#",
          "confidence": 0.875
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [26, 6, 49, 6, 49, 15, 26, 15],
        "text": "Item",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [27, 6, 47, 6, 47, 15, 27, 15],
          "text": "Item",
          "confidence": 0.683
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [273, 5, 315, 4, 315, 16, 273, 16],
        "text": "QTY/HR",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [274, 5, 313, 5, 314, 16, 274, 16],
          "text": "QTY/HR",
          "confidence": 0.947
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [330, 5, 386, 6, 386, 17, 330, 16],
        "text": "Unit price",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [334, 6, 356, 6, 357, 17, 334, 17],
          "text": "Unit",
          "confidence": 0.959
        }, {
          "boundingBox": [359, 6, 385, 6, 385, 18, 359, 17],
          "text": "price",
          "confidence": 0.959
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [419, 6, 461, 6, 461, 16, 419, 16],
        "text": "Amount",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [420, 6, 461, 7, 461, 17, 420, 17],
          "text": "Amount",
          "confidence": 0.959
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [23, 20, 182, 20, 182, 32, 23, 32],
        "text": "Installed office furniture (hours)",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [26, 21, 68, 21, 68, 32, 26, 32],
          "text": "Installed",
          "confidence": 0.862
        }, {
          "boundingBox": [70, 21, 98, 21, 98, 32, 70, 32],
          "text": "office",
          "confidence": 0.958
        }, {
          "boundingBox": [100, 21, 145, 21, 145, 32, 100, 32],
          "text": "furniture",
          "confidence": 0.958
        }, {
          "boundingBox": [147, 21, 182, 21, 183, 33, 147, 32],
          "text": "(hours)",
          "confidence": 0.914
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [305, 22, 314, 22, 313, 31, 304, 32],
        "text": "3",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [308, 22, 313, 22, 314, 31, 308, 32],
          "text": "3",
          "confidence": 0.891
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [364, 21, 384, 21, 385, 30, 364, 31],
        "text": "150",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [366, 21, 384, 21, 385, 31, 366, 31],
          "text": "150",
          "confidence": 0.958
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [443, 21, 459, 21, 459, 30, 443, 31],
        "text": "450",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [443, 21, 459, 21, 459, 30, 443, 31],
          "text": "450",
          "confidence": 0.694
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [4, 37, 15, 37, 14, 47, 4, 47],
        "text": "2",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [7, 37, 14, 37, 14, 47, 7, 47],
          "text": "2",
          "confidence": 0.891
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [26, 36, 131, 37, 131, 48, 26, 47],
        "text": "Herman Miller Aeron",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [27, 37, 66, 37, 66, 47, 27, 48],
          "text": "Herman",
          "confidence": 0.959
        }, {
          "boundingBox": [69, 37, 99, 37, 99, 48, 69, 47],
          "text": "Miller",
          "confidence": 0.959
        }, {
          "boundingBox": [101, 37, 131, 38, 130, 48, 101, 48],
          "text": "Aeron",
          "confidence": 0.958
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [307, 37, 316, 38, 314, 48, 306, 48],
        "text": "4",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [308, 37, 315, 37, 315, 48, 307, 47],
          "text": "4",
          "confidence": 0.895
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [366, 37, 384, 37, 384, 47, 366, 46],
        "text": "900",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [366, 37, 384, 37, 384, 47, 366, 46],
          "text": "900",
          "confidence": 0.950
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [436, 37, 460, 36, 460, 46, 436, 47],
        "text": "3600",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [436, 37, 460, 36, 460, 46, 436, 47],
          "text": "3600",
          "confidence": 0.890
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [26, 52, 100, 53, 100, 63, 26, 62],
        "text": "Sonos speakers",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [27, 53, 56, 53, 56, 62, 27, 62],
          "text": "Sonos",
          "confidence": 0.959
        }, {
          "boundingBox": [58, 53, 100, 54, 100, 63, 58, 62],
          "text": "speakers",
          "confidence": 0.959
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [304, 52, 316, 52, 315, 62, 303, 62],
        "text": "3",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [307, 52, 314, 52, 314, 62, 307, 62],
          "text": "3",
          "confidence": 0.886
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [365, 51, 385, 51, 384, 62, 365, 62],
        "text": "320",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [365, 51, 385, 51, 385, 62, 365, 62],
          "text": "320",
          "confidence": 0.928
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [444, 52, 455, 52, 455, 61, 444, 61],
        "text": "96",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [444, 52, 454, 52, 454, 61, 444, 61],
          "text": "96",
          "confidence": 0.570
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [27, 67, 138, 67, 138, 79, 27, 79],
        "text": "Giardino Grande Table",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [28, 68, 69, 68, 69, 80, 28, 79],
          "text": "Giardino",
          "confidence": 0.861
        }, {
          "boundingBox": [71, 68, 109, 68, 109, 80, 71, 80],
          "text": "Grande",
          "confidence": 0.959
        }, {
          "boundingBox": [111, 68, 138, 67, 137, 80, 111, 80],
          "text": "Table",
          "confidence": 0.958
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [303, 68, 315, 66, 317, 76, 305, 78],
        "text": "1",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [308, 67, 314, 66, 316, 76, 309, 77],
          "text": "1",
          "confidence": 0.839
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [366, 67, 383, 68, 383, 77, 366, 77],
        "text": "780",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [366, 67, 383, 67, 382, 77, 366, 76],
          "text": "780",
          "confidence": 0.909
        }]
      }, {
        "language": "en",
        "boundingBox": [442, 68, 460, 67, 460, 77, 442, 77],
        "text": "780",
        "words": [{
          "boundingBox": [442, 67, 460, 67, 460, 76, 442, 77],
          "text": "780",
          "confidence": 0.958
        }]
      }]
    }],
    "pageResults": [{
      "page": 1,
      "tables": [{
        "rows": 4,
        "columns": 4,
        "cells": [{
          "rowIndex": 0,
          "columnIndex": 1,
          "text": "Installed office furniture (hours)",
          "boundingBox": [26, 21, 274, 21, 274, 34, 26, 34],
          "elements": ["#/readResults/0/lines/5/words/0", "#/readResults/0/lines/5/words/1", "#/readResults/0/lines/5/words/2", "#/readResults/0/lines/5/words/3"]
        }, {
          "rowIndex": 0,
          "columnIndex": 2,
          "text": "3",
          "boundingBox": [274, 21, 334, 21, 334, 34, 274, 34],
          "elements": ["#/readResults/0/lines/6/words/0"]
        }, {
          "rowIndex": 0,
          "columnIndex": 3,
          "text": "150",
          "boundingBox": [334, 21, 385, 21, 385, 34, 334, 34],
          "elements": ["#/readResults/0/lines/7/words/0"]
        }, {
          "rowIndex": 1,
          "columnIndex": 0,
          "text": "2",
          "boundingBox": [7, 34, 26, 34, 26, 50, 7, 50],
          "elements": ["#/readResults/0/lines/9/words/0"]
        }, {
          "rowIndex": 1,
          "columnIndex": 1,
          "text": "Herman Miller Aeron",
          "boundingBox": [26, 34, 274, 34, 274, 50, 26, 50],
          "elements": ["#/readResults/0/lines/10/words/0", "#/readResults/0/lines/10/words/1", "#/readResults/0/lines/10/words/2"]
        }, {
          "rowIndex": 1,
          "columnIndex": 2,
          "text": "4",
          "boundingBox": [274, 34, 334, 34, 334, 50, 274, 50],
          "elements": ["#/readResults/0/lines/11/words/0"]
        }, {
          "rowIndex": 1,
          "columnIndex": 3,
          "text": "900",
          "boundingBox": [334, 34, 385, 34, 385, 50, 334, 50],
          "elements": ["#/readResults/0/lines/12/words/0"]
        }, {
          "rowIndex": 2,
          "columnIndex": 1,
          "text": "Sonos speakers",
          "boundingBox": [26, 50, 274, 50, 274, 65, 26, 65],
          "elements": ["#/readResults/0/lines/14/words/0", "#/readResults/0/lines/14/words/1"]
        }, {
          "rowIndex": 2,
          "columnIndex": 2,
          "text": "3",
          "boundingBox": [274, 50, 334, 50, 334, 65, 274, 65],
          "elements": ["#/readResults/0/lines/15/words/0"]
        }, {
          "rowIndex": 2,
          "columnIndex": 3,
          "text": "320",
          "boundingBox": [334, 50, 385, 50, 385, 65, 334, 65],
          "elements": ["#/readResults/0/lines/16/words/0"]
        }, {
          "rowIndex": 3,
          "columnIndex": 1,
          "text": "Giardino Grande Table",
          "boundingBox": [26, 65, 274, 65, 274, 79, 26, 79],
          "elements": ["#/readResults/0/lines/18/words/0", "#/readResults/0/lines/18/words/1", "#/readResults/0/lines/18/words/2"]
        }, {
          "rowIndex": 3,
          "columnIndex": 2,
          "text": "1",
          "boundingBox": [274, 65, 334, 65, 334, 79, 274, 79],
          "elements": ["#/readResults/0/lines/19/words/0"]
        }, {
          "rowIndex": 3,
          "columnIndex": 3,
          "text": "780",
          "boundingBox": [334, 65, 385, 65, 385, 79, 334, 79],
          "elements": ["#/readResults/0/lines/20/words/0"]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

As you can see, you have the array details in the output, looks like interesting for you!

Comment: Nicolas, Thanks you for your effort, actually my main purpose to read the invoice data which is in tabular format and somehow convert it into csv and store in the database. I'm able to get some data in csv but not all the data. I'm also checking form recognizer api.

Comment: You have all you need in this API result, what is the issue? Custom vision is not intended to do some OCR / Read operations